# Bind UiElement DataContext after loading dynamically with XamlReader.Load(...)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, code-behind

Guess this is blatently easy in the end and I'm just on a mind block or something but here goes:

This is basically about a print preview of some shipping labels. As the goal is to be able to use different label designs, I am currently using `XamlReader.Load()` to dynamically load the preview label template from a XAML file (so that it can be modified without having to recompile the program obviously).

```
public UIElement GetLabelPreviewControl(string path)
{
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    UIElement shippingLabel = (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(stream);
    stream.Close();
    return shippingLabel;
}
```

The element loaded is basically a canvas

```
<Canvas Width="576" Height="384" Background="White" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <!-- Formatting Stuff -->
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <!-- Layout template -->
    <TextBlock Margin="30 222 0 0" Text="{Binding Path=Name1}" />
    <!-- More bound elements -->
</Canvas>
```

that is inserted into a border control:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Name="PrintPreview" Width="596" Height="404" Background="LightGray">
</Border>
```

Obviously I'm lazy and don't want to update the DataContext manually on the preview each time the DataContext on the parent changes (as it is also a source of errors) but I'd rather create a Binding in code behind:

```
try
{
    this.PrintPreview.Child = GetLabelPreviewControl(labelPath);
    Binding previewBinding = new Binding();
    previewBinding.Source = this.PrintPreview.DataContext;
    (this.PrintPreview.Child as FrameworkElement).SetBinding(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, previewBinding);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle Exception Stuff here...
}
```

On loading the template it works perfectly. The binding updates all the preview's data fields.

The problem arises when the DataContext changes on the parent. Then this change is not reflected in the loaded preview, but the Context just stays bound to the old object... Is there something wrong with my Binding Expression or what else am I missing here?

Comment: You shouldn't need the DataContext binding at all, as the DataContext is by default inherited from the parent element by [Property Value Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks... that was the mistake. I somehow had the thought in my mind that I had to bind the `DataContext` manually after loading the `UIElement` at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the Binding, because the `DataContext` is by default inherited from the parent element by [Property Value Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.100).aspx).

So just remove it:

```
try
{
    PrintPreview.Child = GetLabelPreviewControl(labelPath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle Exception Stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default mode for a lot of properties is OneWay. Have you tried setting it to two ways like this?

```
try
{
    this.PrintPreview.Child = GetLabelPreviewControl(labelPath);
    Binding previewBinding = new Binding();
    previewBinding.Source = this.PrintPreview.DataContext;
    previewBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay; //Set the binding to Two-Way mode
    (this.PrintPreview.Child as FrameworkElement).SetBinding(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, previewBinding);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle Exception Stuff here...
}
```

Comment: You would only need a two way binding if the binding target would change the bound property, which doesn't happen here.